# How to set my IP address programmatically?

Tags: delphi

How can I set my IP address programmatically?

My application is checking it, using code from [DelphiTricks](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/internet/get_your_own_ip_address.html) (although I am not sure if the code from [About.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa103100a.htm) might not be better)

I want to be able to set the address programmatically for testing purposes. And (I don't know if this is important), I want to be able to do so even I am not attached to any network (on a laptop, on a train).

Comment: Short answer: Unless you are doing system level work in a known environment, usually you **can't**.  The vast majority of systems receive an address through a [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server and randomly mucking with one's IP address can cause the connection to be lost.  If you know the environment you are in and that you *can* safely do this, you'll have to give us something to work with her -- you know, those minor details like what operating system -- and what version of it.  Do you have root/admin access?  The basic stuff.

Comment: You mean change the one that your app sees? A simple conditional compile should do that. just change the code that gets the ip to get a set one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the ip address of your network adapter you can use the [`EnableStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class or the [`AddIPAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinApi method.

Try this sample which uses the WMI.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  Variants,
  ComObj;

procedure  SetStaticIpAddress(const NetworkCard, IPAddress, Mask :string);
const
  WbemUser    ='';
  WbemPassword='';
  WbemComputer='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator   : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService     : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet  : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject     : OLEVariant;
  FOutParams      : OLEVariant;
  vIpAddress      : OLEVariant;
  vMask           : OLEVariant;
  oEnum           : IEnumvariant;
  iValue          : LongWord;
begin
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);

  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where Description="%s"',[NetworkCard]),'WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
  begin
    vIpAddress   := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
    vIpAddress[0]:= IPAddress;
    vMask   := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
    vMask[0]:=  Mask;
    FOutParams:=FWbemObject.EnableStatic(vIpAddress, vMask);
    // 0 - Successful completion, no reboot required
    // 1 - Successful completion, reboot required
    Writeln(Format('ReturnValue  %s',[FOutParams]));
  end
  else
  Writeln('Network card not found');
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      SetStaticIpAddress('Network card name','192.168.1.1','255.255.255.0');
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Comment: +1, what about to [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) something like [`this`](http://serverfault.com/a/39670/98231) ?

Comment: Yes, that is a valid third option :)

Comment: +1 to both. @Rudy, I am trying the code now. A stupid question, though - how do I knwo what value to give for NetworkCard?

Comment: @Mawg, this is the device name of the network card http://i45.tinypic.com/2cra8b7.png

Comment: @RRUZ  that code worked a treat (when I changed the WroteLn to MessageDlg). Thnaks a 1,000,000. You get tha nswer, of course.