# how to change my computer's network settings programmatically?

Tags: delphi, networking, delphi-7

I use my laptop in two network environment (at work and at home) and they have different network settings (ip address, subnet mask, default gateway) so I have to change my network settings everytime I get home and when I arrive at the office.. is there anyway to write a code that can change the settings so that I only have to run a program instead of changing the settings manually?

I've googled a bit and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574843/how-to-set-my-ip-address-programmatically) but I can't find my network card name and it seems that the code only change the ip address and subnet mask but it doesn't change the default gateway.. am I correct?

oh btw, It'll be great if you guys can use delphi programming in answering my question (especially delphi 7)

Comment: I do love those "Obtain automatically" settings. Saves so many headaches...

Comment: What's your operating system? In linux the NetworkManager is able to do that; on windows you can acheive the same result using a batch script; I don't now about MacOs or others OSs

Comment: I'm using windows 7 professional 32 bit.

Answer (score 7):

As you pointed the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574843/how-to-set-my-ip-address-programmatically) posted on this question doesn't change the default gateway, in order to do that you must execute the [`SetGateways`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method as well.

Try this modified version of the original code which allow you setup the ip, mask and default gateway for a network adapter.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  Variants,
  ComObj;

procedure  SetStaticIpAddress(const NetworkCard, IPAddress, Mask, GateWay :string);
const
  WbemUser    ='';
  WbemPassword='';
  WbemComputer='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator   : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService     : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet  : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject     : OLEVariant;
  FOutParams      : OLEVariant;
  vIpAddress      : OLEVariant;
  vGateWays       : OLEVariant;
  vMask           : OLEVariant;
  oEnum           : IEnumvariant;
  iValue          : LongWord;
begin
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);

  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where Description="%s"',[NetworkCard]),'WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
  begin
    vIpAddress   := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
    vIpAddress[0]:= IPAddress;
    vMask   := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
    vMask[0]:=  Mask;
    FOutParams:=FWbemObject.EnableStatic(vIpAddress, vMask);
    // 0 - Successful completion, no reboot required
    // 1 - Successful completion, reboot required
    Writeln(Format('EnableStatic ReturnValue  %s',[FOutParams]));

    vGateWays   := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
    vGateWays[0]:= GateWay;

    FOutParams:=FWbemObject.SetGateways(vGateWays);
    // 0 - Successful completion, no reboot required
    // 1 - Successful completion, reboot required
    Writeln(Format('SetGateways ReturnValue  %s',[FOutParams]));
  end
  else
  Writeln('Network card not found');
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      SetStaticIpAddress('network device','192.168.1.1','255.255.255.0','192.168.1.2');
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Note.. to get the network device name you can use the network connections list

[image]

Comment: I don't see a "Network Connections" menu anywhere.. can you give me the complete directory to access that menu? I'm using windows 7 professional 32 bit.

Comment: Control Panel->Network and Sharing Center->Change adapter settings

Comment: wihout forms, you must create a console application